# Symfony2 Response

Tags: php, symfony, response

I'm trying to send a response to an API for Oauth. Sadly, the Symfony2 docs do a poor job of explaining all the different parts of `$response->headers->set(...);`.

Here's my response section that's inside of my OauthController:

```
    $response = new Response();

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Location', 'url=' . $auth_url);

    return $response->send();
```

The controller must have a `return` statement so, does my code look good or how can I replicate `header('Location: ' . $auth_url);` from normal php?

Thanks!

Comment: Also if you aren't using `RedirectResponse` and want to set the `Location` header directly on a `Response` class, you would do this: `$response->headers->set('Location', $auth_url);`

Comment: Perhaps the error in my code was `url=` in `set('Location', 'url=' . $auth_url);`. That was in an example I followed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to do a redirect, then you can use [`RedirectResponse`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#redirecting-the-user) instead of regular [`Response`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#response):

```
return new RedirectResponse($auth_url);
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick, it's redirecting perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

While @TomaszMadeyski does a good job providing you with a much better alternative, I wanted to take a minute and explain why your code does not work (as it's just fine).

The problem is that a controller much return a response, but it must not *send* the respond. If you look at [the front controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/a7deb7b79f95aff2e9c67eb7e781aa049966dfd0/web/app.php#L29), you'll see that it takes care of sending the response:

```
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
```

The reason behind this is that Symfony allows you to edit the response between the controller and the `send()` (e.g. to add an awesome toolbar or configure the content type).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this insight! So do you mean a toolbar such as an absolutely positions overlay that's *your* html, but that exists overtop of another web page? Similar to stumbleupon.com?

Comment: @Kenny well, you can do everything you want. You can do `$response->setContent('Override the cmplete response content!')` for instance, or first retrieve the content (`getContent()`) and then tweak it. Or do something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a redirect, shouldn't your [HTTP response code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) be one of the codes in the 300 range to indicate a redirect?

Also, you might want to checkout this [Symfony Cookbook article on redirecting](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html).

Comment: You're probably right. But I scrapped the response->send() and used `return new RedirectResponse($auth_url);`. Thanks for the information!